# How I can make Magento 2 sidebar sticky like cart sidebar when scroll to down?

Tags: magento2

I am a beginner to Magento 2 and want to make a sticky sidebar when scrolling down like a cart page summary. I try using jQuery but not working for me. Can anyone help me?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9L0I.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Magento 2 sticky js for this one. Create custom js in your theme and add the below code.
Create a custom JS in your theme:

```
app/design/frontend/[Vendor_Name]/[Your_theme]/web/js/your_custom.js
```

Add the below code in your theme JS

```
define([
"jquery",
"mage/sticky",
], function ($) {
    'use strict';
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.sidebar.sidebar-additional').sticky({
            container: '.columns',
            spacingTop: 100,
            stickyClass: '[sticky-class]'
        });
    });
});
```

**Note:** You can edit **spacingTop** and **stickyClass** as per your requirement. I hope it will work for you.

Comment: thanks for your help its working fine....@Vikram Kumar

Comment: My pleasure. Always ready to help.